# Relationship between two graph optimization problems

Tags: graph-algorithms, np-hardness, np-complete

Let $Q$ be a polynomial time computable graph property of simple, undirected graphs. Consider the following two optimization problems on any input graph:

**P1.** Find a largest induced subgraph of the input graph with property $Q$, or detect if no such subgraph exists. (Largest = maximum number of vertices.)

**P2.** Partition the vertices of the input graph, such that the number of partition classes is minimum, and each class induces a subgraph with property $Q$, or detect if no such partition exists.

Several choices of $Q$ lead to classical problems, for example:

- $Q(G)$="$G$ is an independent set." Then **P1** is the max independent set problem, **P2** is minimum coloring. Both are NP-hard.
- $Q(G)$="$G$ is a clique." Then **P1** is the max clique problem, **P2** is minimum clique cover. Both are NP-hard.
- $Q(G)$="$G$ is Hamiltonian." Then **P1** looks for a largest circle, **P2** looks for a minimum partition into Hamiltonian subgraphs. Both are NP-hard.
- $Q(G)$="$G$ is connected." Then **P1** looks for the largest connected component, while **P2** looks for the number of connected components. Both are solvable in polynomial time.
- $Q(G)$="$G$ has a perfect matching." Then **P1** looks for a maximum matching, if the input graph has at least one edge, otherwise there is no subgraph with the property. The solution for **P2** is the trivial partition with one class if the input graph has a perfect matching, or otherwise there is no feasible partition. Both cases are solvable in polynomial time.

**Question:** is there any (preferably natural) choice for the property $Q$, which makes **one** of the problems **P1,P2** NP-hard, while the other is solvable in polynomial time?

Comment: There is linear/integer programming duality going on in this question, but I don't know the details off the top of my head.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One example: choosing the property "G contains a node that has an edge to all nodes in G" makes P1 trivial in $O(n + m)$ (pick node with largest degree), but makes P2 the problem of finding the minimum size dominating set, which is NP-hard.

Comment: Nice example! I wonder if there is an example the other way around: P1 is NP-hard, while P2 is solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro oops, I misread the answer. misleading comment deleted.